# Program to compare two xml file

Tags: xml, compare

I would like to compare two xml files using some kind of program ( may be using XLST or Java), but the actual need is I would like to exclude some xpath's for comparision. If it is program to be written may be I can configure them in some configuration file. But not sure much about XSLT. Is there any open source library which do this action ? any tool which runs on the batch mode will do for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This supports java and .net](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) : XMLUnit

Comment: Yeah, I use XMLUnit for some unit testing.  It works fairly well and isn't too bad to learn.   Get Eclipse IDE for Java developers and then download the XMLUnit .jar files and create a new project with the jars on your path.

Comment: Is that having the facility to run in the batch mode and ignoring the xpaths?

Comment: @srinannapa just strip the nodes you don't want to compare out of the document. Or write your own DifferenceListener.

Answer (score 5):

Beyond Compare 3 lets you compare two xml files.

1. Download Beyond Compare 3 (30 days of free usage - don't have to be consecutive days)
2. Download the [XML tidied with attributes sorted](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformats_alt) extension
3. Follow the Beyond Compare 3 [instructions](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformats) to add the extension.
4. Then this screenshot shows how to use the extension:
   [image: using the XML tidied with attributes sorted extension]